# Filter array of object with dynamic array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I currently working on filtering an array of object.

The array of objects goes like this

```
var arrayObj = [
        {
            "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
            "Dhuhr": "11:43 (WIB)",
            "Asr": "14:48 (WIB)",
            "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
            "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)"
        },
        {
            "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
            "Dhuhr": "11:43 (WIB)",
            "Asr": "14:47 (WIB)",
            "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
            "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)"
        }
    ]
```

---

And I have the Array that can change but the range is only 0 to 4. the example is like this

```
var arrayFind = [3, 0, 4]
```

What I want to achieve is the `arrayObj` will filter based on `arrayFind`, example the output is like this

```
var arrayObj = [
        {
            "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
            "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
            "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)"
        },
        {
            "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
            "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
            "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)"
        }
    ]
```

How do I achieve that ? I tried to use `map` and `_.pickBy` but still stuck.
Thank you so much

Comment: Yes you're right, its risky not to filter object by the key names. But in my case the objects from the API not  changing so I'll look into that if something change, thank you for point it out :) @kikon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys and then using `map()` to do it

```js
var arrayObj = [
        {
            "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
            "Dhuhr": "11:43 (WIB)",
            "Asr": "14:48 (WIB)",
            "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
            "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)"
        },
        {
            "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
            "Dhuhr": "11:43 (WIB)",
            "Asr": "14:47 (WIB)",
            "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
            "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)"
        }
    ]
    
var arrayFind = [3, 0, 4]

let result = arrayObj.map(e => {
  let keys = Object.keys(e)
  let obj = {}
  arrayFind.forEach(a => {
    obj[keys[a]] = e[keys[a]]
  })
  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```